# Every $\sigma$ finite measure is absolutely continuous with respect to a finite measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$- finite measure on $(X,M)$. Prove that there exists a finite measure $\lambda$ on $M$ such that $\lambda\ll\mu$ and $\mu\ll\lambda$.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to start on this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some hints:

1. What would happen if you have a measure $\lambda = f\,\mathrm d\mu$? Say, if $f > 0$ everywhere? Does integral of positive function w.r.t. $\lambda$ has to be infinite if $\lambda$ is infinite?
2. To find such $f$, think of the fact that there exists an increasing sequence of sets on which $\lambda$ is finite, and union covers the whole space. How would you define $f$ on each of those sets?

Comment: Thanks. I completed my solution using your hint! Was much easier than I expected.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: For each $n$, $\mu(E_n) <\infty$ by $\sigma$-finiteness, and define a new measure $$\mu_n = \frac{2^{-n}}{\mu(E_n)}\mu_{E_n}.$$

Rest hidden in spoilers:

> Then $\|\mu_n \| = 2^{-n}$, so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|\mu_n\| < \infty$, so the series of the measures $\mu_n$ converges in the normed space of measures (I assume you defined this in class). Then, define $\lambda = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu_n$ and obtain $\mu \ll \nu \ll \mu$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though we have not defined normed space of measures. But I think I see where this is going.