# On absolutely continuous measures..

Tags: measure-theory

Is it true that 
if $\mu$ is a finite measure and $\nu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu$, then $\nu$ is a finite measure.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510782/every-sigma-finite-measure-is-absolutely-continuous-with-respect-to-a-finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, the Lebesgue measure is absolutely continuous with respect to the gaussian probability measure $$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}dx.$$